# After Installing Win XP, could not able to load Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-xp

My System was having Windows XP in `C:` drive, then I installed Ubuntu in `F:` Drive. Everything was going fine.

But I re-installed Windows XP due to some reasons and I did take care of `F:` Drive where Ubuntu 14.04 is already installed. After Successfully installation of Windows XP SP3, I am not getting any GRUB window. It is directly booting to Xp.

I think GRUB of Ubuntu might have gone. HOw can I fix it??
Can I do repair or something using installation disk??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to repair your [GRUB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_GRUB). In order to do that...here is the link which will help you: [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Answer (score 0):

1. Insert your Ubuntu CD, reboot your computer and set it to boot from CD in the BIOS and boot into a live session. You can also use a LiveUSB if you have created one in the past.
2. Install and run Boot-Repair
3. Click "Recommended Repair".
4. Now reboot your system. The usual GRUB boot menu should appear. If it does not, hold Left Shift while booting. You will be able to choose between Ubuntu and Windows.

[Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows) is the recommended help page